# React JS: How to implement scroll bar in one particular div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, frontend, scrollbar

I am creating a movie app. I am facing some problem on implementing the scroll bar.

While scrolling I want the header div to remain where it is. I don't want it to disappear while scrolling down. But the div located vertically bottom to the header must be scrollable.

This can be found in amazon.in

On searching Harry Potter, this page loads
[image]

On scrolling down, you can see that the header remains fixed.
[image]

How can I implement this in React?? Please share the necessary code/documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This actually has nothing to do with React. This has to do with basic HTML and CSS knowledge.

Here is my preferred method:

```html
<div id="navbar">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#content {
  margin-top: /* size of navbar */ 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add scroll bar in a `div` by using `overflow` property with some height.

CSS:

```css
float:left; 
width:1000px; 
overflow-y: auto; 
height: 100px;
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="ScrollStyle"> 
  Scrollbar Test!<br/> 
  Scrollbar Test!<br/> 
</div>
```